# Is it safe to use the miredo-client?

Tags: linux, security, fedora, ipv6

This is how I can surf websites behind IPv6 networks under Fedora 14

```
before:
ping6 ipv6.google.com
connect: Network is unreachable


solution: with root just:
yum install -y miredo-client
sed -i "s/ServerAddress teredo.remlab.net/ServerAddress teredo.ipv6.microsoft.com/g" /etc/miredo/miredo.conf
service miredo-client restart


after:
ping6 ipv6.google.com
PING ipv6.google.com(2a00:1450:8004::67) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2a00:1450:8004::67: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=147 ms
64 bytes from 2a00:1450:8004::67: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=111 ms
64 bytes from 2a00:1450:8004::67: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=142 ms
64 bytes from 2a00:1450:8004::67: icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=50.1 ms
```

Is there any way to be assured that when I'm using this "teredo" type of tunneling I can be safe from attacks like MITM?
Is it safe to use this kind of "tunneling"?
How can I be sure that the "teredo.ipv6.microsoft.com" is not sniffing my traffic?
Thank you for any pointings, corrections!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just as safe from MITM as you would be normally, in general. Teredo "servers", like teredo.ipv6.microsoft.com, don't actually forward your packets. They serve the important purpose of handling getting around NAT, and allowing your computer to communicate with the machines that actually do, namely, Teredo "relays."

Many IPv6 enabled sites, and a handful of major ISPs run Teredo relays, so often, either a machine near the path your data would already be taking, or a machine near the one hosting the site you are visiting can directly handle the traffic itself, thus meaning you are no more vulnerable to MITM attacks than normally.

Teredo "servers" cannot sniff traffic, all they will see are so-called "bubble packets" from the relay handling the actual traffic, and ICMP traffic (since servers do directly forward pings)

It is, however, only as safe as the internet usually is. It is still possible for your traffic to be sniffed if it travels over wireless, it is still possible for your ISP to sniff your traffic, and it is certainly still possible for your destination to see all the traffic you send it, so don't fall into the trap of thinking Teredo itself *provides* any security, it simply does not make you much (if any) less secure.

Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling